# Deserialize message from JSON to POJO using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, pojo

How would you deserialize a JSON document to a POJO using Jackson if you didn't know exactly what type of POJO to use without inspecting the message. Is there a way to register a set of POJOs with Jackson so it can select one based on the message?

The scenario I'm trying to solve is receiving JSON messages over the wire and deserializing to one of several POJOs based on the content of the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a mechanism that you are describing.
I think you will have to inspect the json yourself:

```
    Map<String, Class<?>> myTypes = ... 
    String json = ...
    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);
    String type = node.get("type").getTextValue();
    Object myobject = mapper.readValue(json, myTypes.get(type));
```

If you don't have a type field you will have to inspect the fields in the JsonNode in order to resolve the type.

Comment: One additional suggestion: you can also convert directly from the tree (`JsonNode`) into POJO by: "Object myObject = mapper.treeAsValue(node, type);".
This is not only more efficient, but also allows you to modify the tree if you want (add or remove nodes, change values).

Answer (score 0):

If you have flexibility in your JSON library, take a look at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). It has a [BeanDeserializer](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/deser/BeanDeserializer.html) that can be used for this very purpose.

Comment: It's not really clear how to use that class to deserialize to a specific POJO given the contents of the message..

Answer (score 0):

BeanDeserializer, in Jackson is deprecated. 
However, I had the same problem and I solved it using Google's [GSon](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types). Have a look at this example.

Given your POJO data type:

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}
```

- Serialization

  ```
  BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String json = gson.toJson(obj);  // ==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
  ```

Note that you can not serialize objects with circular references since that will result in infinite recursion.

- Deserialization

  ```
  BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);
  ```